# Tone control circuit produces loud noise on disconnect

Tags: audio, noise, tone-control

I built a tone control circuit using an [AN5835](https://www.rcscomponents.com/datasheets/AN5835%2C36.pdf) chip and it seems to work fine, except that it produces a loud "thud" when turning it off (cutting power out). What can I do to eliminate or attenuate this "thud"?

The circuit is installed between an MP3 module and a car audio amp. The MP3 is fed by an independent 5 V supply. The tone control and amplifier are powered from a switched 12 V, 3 A power supply. Both power supplies are "always on" so they are connected in parallel to AC via a DPST switch, so both lines, hot and neutral, are switched simultaneously. The whole contraption runs from 127 V AC.

I blame the noise on the tone control because it happens if I manually disconnect the power cable to this circuit while the rest remains turned on.

I had previously connected only the MP3 and amplifier to an ATX power supply and it worked fine. I used to turn it on/off by bridging the corresponding ATX pin to ground and had no noise problems. The sound signal was directed from module to a double gang potentiometer and then to line level inputs of the amp. Each channel from the pot goes to 2 RCA connectors to feed the 4 channel amplifier. I had been using this configuration almost daily for about year and a half. The potentiometer also had a switch which I used to control the ATX's power state.

When I added the tone control, it produced a loud sound on the speakers when turning on or off and also electrical noise from the fan made its way through. I tried feeding the tone control through a DC/DC isolator, but did not work. Also tried the isolator to feed the fan, but didn't work either, the noise was still there. I also disliked that the ATX used to heat up a little even when turned off.

So, with all those problems I decided to try a different power supply and it works a lot better. This power supply does not have a fan, so there is no noise from that. This arrangement does not have the "thud" when turning on, but it has it when turning off.

With the new power supply I also tried to put a small coil of enamel copper wire (somewhat like an inductor) in series with the tone control, in the positive lead, but to no noticeable effect.

At this point the sound I'm getting is acceptable. There is a little "hiss", only noticeable at very low volume and when the room is very silent.

The tutorial I followed in order to assemble the circuit did explain some of the components but no special mention of the power input is given.

This is the diagram from the tutorial which I followed closely, except that on the bass control capacitors I put two of the proposed ones in parallel. For everything else I used the given values.

[image]

This would be the complete schematic (Speakers omitted)

[image]

Are there any extra components I can add or change to reduce the turning off bang? What is the function of the 1000 μF capacitor on the 12 V input of the circuit? Can changing its value help this situation?

A possible explanation for the noise would be appreciated, even if speculative or "general case". Could it be a defect or characteristic of the AN5835/AN5836 chip? I do not know the manufacturer of the specific one I bought, but I have read a couple of spec sheets for it and I did not find info on noise when turning on/off.

EDIT: I've been asked for the "exact diagram", I do not have such. The tutorial/article I followed provides PCB templates one is supposed to print and transfer to bakelite and etch. I did not, instead, I mounted everything on a breadboard and once I got confident, I transferred to stripboard. I used 3 pin connectors for input and output, and a cable with a quick connector from power supply to the circuit.

- Iteration 1: ATX power supply, MP3 module connected to +5V, Car amplifier connected to +12V. Worked fine, no noises. Lacked bass which I blame on the amp.
- Iteration 2: ATX, MP3 module on +5V, Car amplifier and tone control circuit on the +12V output from the ATX. This power supply as only 1 rail for each voltage.
  Here is where 2 noises appeared. The "thud" when powering on/off and "RRRRR..." noise from the fan. The potentiometer mentioned before was removed and the tone control took it's place in the signal path.
- 2.1 Added this component in between ATX and Tone Control: "HI-Link HLK-1D1212 12V to 12V 1W 84mA DC - DC Isolation Switching Power Supply Module". It had no effect on the noise from the fan.
- 2.2 cut the 12V power cable to the fan. Noise from fan dissapears.
- 2.3 Added isolator between ATX and fan, noise returns.
- 2.4 Connected fan to different 12V (In this ATX the fan is powered from a different connection point but I'm not certain is it is the same rail as the main output). The noise is still there.
- 2.5 Connect fan to +5V. The noise is still there, only that at lower pitch.

During all of this tests, if I manually connect/disconnect the power cable to the tone control circuit, the "thud" is produced.

- Iteration 3 (actual): Removed the ATX completely and installed a dedicated mini 5V supply for the MP3 module, and a generic, fanless 12V switching power supply which feeds in parallel the amp and the tone control. In this case, there is only one "thud" when turning off via the switch or by manually pulling the power connector to the tone control. There is no noise when turning on via the switch and all components are connected. However, if the power supply is on, the amp is on and I manually push in the power connector to the tone control, then it produces the "thud" noise.

Comment: It is made by Panasonic. Many poorly designed audio ICs make a POP noise when turned on or turned off.

Comment: Please show the exact schematic you used and how it interfaced with your other audio parts on the output side. Please also indicate which power supplies you disabled first and how you did that.

Comment: @Andyaka, I do not have an "exact" diagram. I made the circuit on breadboard first and then transferred to stripboard. I added pictures of the board mid-process in hopes it helps. I also added the general steps.

Comment: A schematic is needed to avoid guesswork.

Comment: @Andyaka I updated the general schematic. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Sounds like your standard single supply + DC blocking capacitor setup with its associated poor turn-on and turn-off behavior.